# Windows Explorer closes when unknown script runs

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-11

Is there any reason a script would run that would close the Windows Explorer? I have it happening on a Windows 11 PC. I see the cmd pop-up but the text that should display does not because the cmd closes right away. Windows Explorer closes or crashes with whatever is being run in the script. I do not know where to search in the Windows system logs to find what the script/process is. It happens a few times a day.

This is a home PC that I have full control over.

Comment: its unlikely that the event has produced a meaningful log. I'd probably use CPUMon to capture and then just wait for it to happen.

Comment: What can you tell us about the script, and would it be possible to include it in your post?

Comment: @harrymc I do not know what the script is that is running. I had to use a logmein session on the PC and then it started happening.

Comment: See if the Event Viewer has more information. Check if you have matching `.dmp` files in the folder `C:\Windows\Minidump`, and if you do and if their dates correspond, zip some up and post them online.

Comment: @harrymc - File Explorer crashing wouldn't result in a .dmp file being created.  File Explorer crashing suggests an application that interfaces with File Explorer is installed and is the source of the script being ran and File Explorer crashing.

Comment: @Ramhound: I believe you, but if the script crashed first we might have a clue to what it was.

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) by Microsoft. Make it run in the background, and when the CMD prompt pops up you have to take a look at the time. Next, in Process Monitor you have to use `cmd.exe` as a filter and based on the time the CMD popped up, you should be able to pinpoint what launched `cmd.exe`.

You can use [this](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=process%20monitor%20filter%20by%20process) query on youtube to find out more about filtering a process with **Process Monitor**.

I would also take a look at what processes are being launched at **Startup** by using [Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns), also by Microsoft. Once in **Autoruns** make sure to go to  **Options > Scan Options...** and tick **Check VirusTotal.com** and **Submit Unknown Images**. Next hit **Rescan** and accept the prompt popping up related to **virustotal**, and wait a few seconds until you'll get the rating from **virustotal**.

Also, have you installed any game booster programs? If I recall correctly some had the function to close Windows Explorer to make the games run better. If that is true, then that program might misbehave by closing Windows Explorer at random times.

Comment: The pc isn't used for any games. Trying to recall any other software that would have been installed.

Comment: I see. Maybe Windows theming programs of any sort?

Comment: ohmyposh is installed for PowerShell7

Comment: Maybe try to disable that at first and see if you still get that pop-up, before you go through the hassle of learning how Processor Monitor works?

Comment: To expand on this perfect answer.. FILTER FILTER FILTER!  There is very little this tool won't provide you but you will need to use the filters to make the information consumable by normal human beings.  If you see too much information, use your brain to filter down further.  You might even need to back those out and go another route but this tool will indeed tell you what you want to know.

Comment: I was able to capture it with ProcessMonitor. I caught over 16,150 processes that ran in that quick instance.

Comment: @rd51 svchost.exe is what creates the process that starts and ends up closing win explorer

Comment: Hmm. Sometimes malware [disguises](https://www.avast.com/c-what-is-svchost-file#:~:text=Svchost.exe%20processes%20are%20usually,sensitive%20areas%20of%20the%20computer.) itself as svchost.exe. I would run a system scan. In the meantime you can ask someone to read the log of Process Monitor (generated after you save the session in Process Monitor), maybe there is a chance others will be able to identify a different process than svchost.exe as the culprit. I would do it myself, but I strongly believe there are people way better than me at interpreting the results.